# Finding CSS element position (top and left) after rotate transformation has been applied via jquery

Tags: jquery, css, position, transformation, offset

I'm using .offset() to find the top and left properties. But due to a rotation (which I replicated in a test object at the exact same coordinates), it still does not match the position. Do I have to count the nr of degrees with the top and left properties?

I can't do this, because internally the webkit-transform: rotate(xdeg) is changed to:

-webkit-transform: matrix(0.9975640502598242, -0.0697564737441253, 0.0697564737441253, 0.9975640502598242, 0, 0)

So how can I get the nr of degrees from this? (it's randomly applied so I can't just get it from a class or what not)

Comment: Your xy is calculated by  newX = a * x + c * y + 0 and newY =  b * x + d * y + 0, where a,b,c,d are the first four arguments, and 0,0 are the last two, of the matrix. to get the newX and newY.

Comment: Thanks @Caspar Kleijne, that doesn't seem to work. Just to be clear, you are saying: get the top and left of the rotated element via offset(); then do left = a * left + c * top + 0 (5th element) and top = b * left + d * top + 0 (6th element)?

Comment: That is if the origin of the rotation is (0,0) relative to the display ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put 0,0 thought the same transformation matrix (e.g. using [sylvester](http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/)), and add them to the position of the element. Not sure if there is an easier/already in the browser method to do this too.